# Reshape data in Pandas - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reshape my data from wide to long but I need to consider both vertical indexes and horizontal columns and it's not really working.

My current table looks like this:

```
  Rate      FY2014   FY 2015   FY 2016   FY 2017 
   1.1       15.87    45.85      72.65     78.54
   2.1       78.54    78.45      95.87     78.94
   3.1       45.87    64.52      37.82     97.57
```

And I want to reshape this data so that the numbers under each FY can have it's own column. For example, I want something like this as my final table.

```
  Values     Rate    Year
   15.87     1.1     FY2014
   78.54     2.1     FY2014
   45.87     3.1     FY2014
   45.85     1.1     FY2015
   78.45     2.1     FY2015
   64.52     3.1     FY2015
   72.65     1.1     FY2016
   95.87     2.1     FY2016
   37.82     3.1     FY2016
```

I'm new to Python and I've tried something like pd.reshape or Transpose but I couldn't get the result I wanted. Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: `df.melt('Rate', var_name='Year')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
In [1806]: df = df.melt(id_vars='Rate', var_name='Year', value_name='Values')

In [1807]: df
Out[1807]: 
    Rate    Year  Values
0    1.1  FY2014   15.87
1    2.1  FY2014   78.54
2    3.1  FY2014   45.87
3    1.1  FY2015   45.85
4    2.1  FY2015   78.45
5    3.1  FY2015   64.52
6    1.1  FY2016   72.65
7    2.1  FY2016   95.87
8    3.1  FY2016   37.82
9    1.1  FY2017   78.54
10   2.1  FY2017   78.94
11   3.1  FY2017   97.57
```

**OR:**

Use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
In [1814]: df.set_index('Rate').stack().reset_index(name='Values').rename(columns={'level_1': 'Year'})
Out[1814]: 
    Rate    Year  Values
0    1.1  FY2014   15.87
1    1.1  FY2015   45.85
2    1.1  FY2016   72.65
3    1.1  FY2017   78.54
4    2.1  FY2014   78.54
5    2.1  FY2015   78.45
6    2.1  FY2016   95.87
7    2.1  FY2017   78.94
8    3.1  FY2014   45.87
9    3.1  FY2015   64.52
10   3.1  FY2016   37.82
11   3.1  FY2017   97.57
```